# Run awk on file being decoded continuously and then print patterns from decode file using awk

Tags: awk, sed

I a command which decodes binary logs to ascii format 
From ASCII format file, I need to grep some patters using awk and print them

How can this be done?

What I have tried is as below in shell script and it does not work.

command > file.txt | awk /pattern/ | sed/pattern/

Also I need command to continously decode file and keep printing patterns on file being updated

Thanks in advance

Comment: `...>file.txt | awk ...` Is an error, you have redirected the output of `cmd` to a file, you can't also redirect it to a `|`. You don't say if you really need `file.txt`. So the simplest is `cmd | decode | awk ...` awk can do most anything `sed` can do. For a one-off use, continue appending sed. For something that will be in production for years, figure out how to do the required substitutions in `awk` and save a process. Good luck.

Comment: Also this Q is very vague. Readers expect to see reproducible cases and evidence. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and include sample input, expected output, real code, current output, error msgs and your comments about where you have having trouble. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> command to continously decode file and keep printing patterns

The first question is exactly how *continuously* manifests itself.  Most log files grow by being appended to -- for our purpose here, by some unknown external process -- and are periodically rotated.  If you're going to continuously decode them, you're going to have to keep track of log rotation.

Can `command` continuously decode, or do you intend to re-run `command` periodically, picking up where you left off?  If the latter, you might instead try some variation of:

```
cat log | command | awk
```

If that can't be done, you'll have to record where each iteration terminates, something like:

```
touch pos
while -f pos
do
    command | awk -v status=pos script.awk > output || rm pos
done
```

where `script.awk` skips input until `NR` equals the value of the number in the `pos` file.  It then processes lines until EOF, and overwrites `pos` with its final `NR`.  On error, it calls `exit 1`, and the file is removed, and the loop terminates.

I recommend you ignore sed, and put all the pattern matching logic in one awk script.  It will be easier to understand and cheaper to execute.

Comment: I figured out the way to do this. I put the command in infinite while loop which would suffice